# Experiencing slow first time loads with Web Apps on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm experiencing very slow load time (~10sec) for the first time a page is loaded by a browser. Once the page has loaded it will load quickly for subsequent requests for the page. I suspect that the application is loading the resources for page into memory. Is there a way to 'pre-load' all of the pages of the application before use? And to keep them loaded? It seems that after some time the slow load will return, possibly because of garbage collection.

I've tried a bunch of the strategies advised by other comments and questions. The Web App is set to be 'Always-On' and it is compiled into a single DLL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may follow the troubleshooting steps in case if you haven’t checked earlier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation

Comment: One other thing I'd ask is what is the 1st page you're loading? For example, I found that with MVC5 and Identity, the User Data Store was very slow to load initially....EF can be quite slow too. I migrated to the micro ORM 'Dapper' for db access.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Application Insights and use profiling to identify the bottleneck. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler